# Reducing recursive calls on pow recursion method?

Tags: java

Had a question on how to reduce the amount of recursive calls on a self implementation of the pow method. Here is what I wrote, can this be improved?

```
public static int pow(double a, int b) {
    boolean isNegative = false;

    if(b < 0) {
        isNegative = true;
    }

    if(b == 0) {
        return 1;
    } 
    else if(b == 1) {
        return (isNegative ? (1 / b) : b);
    }

    return (isNegative ? ((1 / b) * (1 / b) * pow(a, b + 2)) : (b * b * pow(a, b - 2)));
}
```

Comment: You could put more `else if`s, but I wouldn't do that. In fact, I would remove your `else if` to simplify the code.

Comment: What I would have said is; use a loop and you get no recursion at all, you can't do better than that. Don't think its the answer they are looking for however. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be improved.

Think about it this way:

- If b is even, then a^b = a^(b/2) * a^(b/2).
- If b is odd, then a^b = a^(b/2) * a^(b/2) * a (where / means integer division).

Code (brain-compiled, coffee hasn't kicked in yet, etc.):

```
public static double pow(double a, int b) {
    if (b < 0)
        return 1 / pow(a, -b);
    if (b == 0)
        return 1;
    double halfPow = pow(a, b/2);
    if (b % 2 == 0)
        return halfPow * halfPow;
    else
        return halfPow * halfPow * a;
}
```

This gives you O(log b) recursive calls, as opposed to O(n) in your solution.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (b == 0) return 1` and `if (b % 2 == 0)`?  But +1 for a good textbook example of reducing an O(n) operation to O(log2n).  Add `if (b == 1) return a` to save one more level of calls.

Comment: You're getting `a` and `b` mixed up... just as the OP does :(

Comment: You can use recursion to handle negatives. `if (b < 0) return 1/pow(a,-b)` assuming you don't care if `b == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: You might want to return `double` ;)

Comment: See? I told you my coffee hadn't kicked in yet, and blindly copying the code from the OP didn't help much... :)

Comment: I still think that tests should be introduced before even trying to improve or fix the code (other than the return type). Without tests, the OP should have little confidence in any solution, and should be nervous of making any further changes.

Comment: In short, I agree that correctness is more important than performance. Suggesting test cases is a important thing to add in an interview IMHO. e.g.the OP forgets to use `b = -b` when he finds that b is negative. Any test negative value of `b` would find that quickly. I would suggest the OP try `pow(1, Integer.MIN_VALUE)` to see what happens. ;)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It's an interview question. I suppose that the general idea is sufficient, and full-blown specification, documentation and unit tests are not necessary. Anyway, who'd want to write their own `pow` function for production use?

Comment: @Thomas, I would expect an interviewee to suggest unit test cases in an interview, even try some basic ones in their head. i.e. show they use them in regularly. You might also mention you would use Math.pow() in production or an alternative as it is rather expensive.

Comment: @Thomas: In an interview question, I'd still give much more credit to someone who said, "I'd start by writing some unit tests" than to someone who started off by writing code. Sadly that rarely comes up :( "Full-blown" specification may not be relevant, but asking the interviewer whether `a` will always be a "real" double (not infinite or NaN) and whether `b` will always be non-negative would be good. Documentation probably isn't relevant, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Fundamentally, you've got three problems:

- The code doesn't work (as of the edit, it now completely ignores `a`)
- The code is too complicated
- The code is recursing more than you want it to

Trying to fix the third of these without fixing the first is pointless.

Your first port of call should be some unit tests. They will prove very quickly that your code is currently broken, and give you some confidence that when you've fixed it, you can then change it and know whether or not you've broken anything.

Then you should aim to simplify it. For example, you could easily start your method with:

```
if (b < 0)
{
    return 1 / pow(a, -b);
}
```

... then you don't need to worry about negative values of `b` any more.

*Finally* you can look at what you've got left and try to turn a recursive solution into an iterative solution.

Comment: @Brent: You're now *never* using the value of `a`. I don't think that's right, either. First get something *working*, then make it simpler, then make it faster.